# NoReverseMatch at /profile/create/ django

Tags: python, django

Suddenly my form for creating a new account has stopped working..the error that comes up is

```
    NoReverseMatch at /profile/create/
    NoReverseMatch at /profile/create/

Reverse for 'None' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

    Request Method:     POST
    Request URL:    http://visionsofearth.co.uk/profile/create/
    Django Version:     1.3.1
    Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
    Exception Value:    

    Reverse for 'None' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

    Exception Location:     /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in reverse, line 336
    Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
    Python Version:     2.4.3
    Python Path:    

    ['/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pip-0.8.2-py2.4.egg',
     '/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django_filebrowser-3.0-py2.4.egg',
     '/usr/lib64/python24.zip',
     '/usr/lib64/python2.4',
     '/usr/lib64/python2.4/plat-linux2',
     '/usr/lib64/python2.4/lib-tk',
     '/usr/lib64/python2.4/lib-dynload',
     '/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages',
     '/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/PIL',
     '/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages',
     '/home/visionso/kitchen']
```

would anybody know how to fix the error?

Comment: This exception is caused by improper arguments to `reverse()` or `{% url %}`. You need to show us the code.

Comment: ..and also your `urls.py`.

Answer (score 0):

By reading the error:

```
Reverse for 'None' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

You are passing a variable to reverse() which actually is `None` and has no `kwargs` (ie: `reverse(NULL_VARIABLE, {})`)